# Passing multiple optional default values in TestNG with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

As per the documentation,

> Specifies that the current parameter is optional. TestNG will pass in
> a specified default value, or null if none is specified.

Is there any walkaround to pass two default values one for the browser=chrome and browserVersion=90 as default values?

```
@Parameters({"browser", "browserVersion"})
@BeforeClass
private void setUp(ITestContext context,@Optional("Chrome") String browser,String browserVersion)
{
}
```

Comment: why you don't add `@Optional("90")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Optional` can be added multiple times to parameters, in your case add  `@Optional("90")`,

Another [example](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/classes/org.testng.annotations.Optional):

> ```
> public void testCopyUrl(@Optional String httpStreamUrl, @Optional String httpStreamMD5) throws Exception {
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Based on user7294900, comment added is an answer .

```
private void setUp(ITestContext context,@Optional("Chrome") String browser,@Optional("92") String browserVersion)
{   System.out.println("browser is setUp "+browser);
    System.out.println("browserVersion is setUp "+browserVersion);
}
```